# I want the link to send a request but not pull the page up. Is that possible?

Tags: java, python, html

This is a hard question to ask because I have no idea if what I want to do is possible and if it is what code would do it.

I have an Arduino running a web server that can control 8 relays.

To turn a relay on and off I use.

http://192.168.1.178/?led1=on

I would like to make a HTML page that has on and off buttons.

So far everything I try when I press the link above it loads up a page from the web server running on the Arduino. But I would like to stay on my custom HTML page with out bringing that page up.

So basically I want the link to send a request but not pull the page up. Is that possible?

My code is:

```
<form  method="get">   
  <p>Led controller</p> 
  <br>led1 <input type="button" name="led1" value="on"> 
  <br>led2 <input type="submit" name="led2" value="on"> 
  <br>led3 <input type="submit" name="led3" value="on"> 
  <br>led4 <input type="submit" name="led4" value="on"> 
  <br>led5 <input type="submit" name="led5" value="on"> 
  <br>led6 <input type="submit" name="led6" value="on"> 
  <br>led7 <input type="submit" name="led7" value="on"> 
  <br>led8 <input type="submit" name="led8" value="on"> 
  <br>All 
  <input type="submit" name="all" value="on"><input type="submit" name="all" value="off"> 
</form>
```

Comment: If I understand your question, then yes. But you do it in the web-browser with a [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [tag:javascript]. You may also need [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: You have provided us a link to an intranet. We cant view your demo publicly

Comment: @OmariOmosa It's an 8 relay arduino; there isn't much to see. OP has an HTTP remote control.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to click the link and update the button status on the same page without moving away from the page. You should take a look at Ajax, which will allow you to do what you need. There are many great Ajax tut orials for beginners. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: @michael-harker please give as a piece of your code .

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what is 8 relay arduino haha

Comment: When I click http://192.168.1.178/?led1=on It turns the relay on but also brings open the web server page running on the Arduino. I need the link to change the relay position but I don't want to see the web server. I would like to write my own HTML page with on and off buttons that activate the HTML links but don't load through to the web server running on the Arduino.

Comment: @Omari [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Products) primarily makes [SBC boards](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/27276/l/arduino-now-a-single-board-computer?displayFullThread=true).

Comment: <html><body><form method=get>
<p>Led controller</p>
<br>led1  <input type=submit name=led1 value=on>
<br>led2  <input type=submit name=led2 value=on>
<br>led3  <input type=submit name=led3 value=on>
<br>led4  <input type=submit name=led4 value=on>
<br>led5  <input type=submit name=led5 value=on>
<br>led6  <input type=submit name=led6 value=on>
<br>led7  <input type=submit name=led7 value=on>
<br>led8  <input type=submit name=led8 value=on>
<br>All <input type=submit name=all value=on><input type=submit name=all value=off>
</from></html></body>

Comment: That is all I get from looking at the source in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example from [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), you could define a basic AJAX request and do something like

```js
var device = "http://192.168.1.178/";

function reqListener() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

function setLed(i, state) {
  if (state === undefined || state !== 'on') state = 'off';
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  if (i === 'all') {
    oReq.open("GET", device + "?all=" + state);
  } else {
    oReq.open("GET", device + "?led" + i + "=" + state);
  }
  oReq.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Turn Led 1 On" onClick="setLed(1,'on')" />
  <input type="button" value="Turn Led 1 Off" onClick="setLed(1,'off')" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Turn Led 2 On" onClick="setLed(2,'on')" />
  <input type="button" value="Turn Led 2 Off" onClick="setLed(2,'off')" />
  <br/>
  <hr /><br/>
  <input type="button" value="Turn All On" onClick="setLed('all','on')" />
  <input type="button" value="Turn All Off" onClick="setLed('all','off')" />
  <br/>
</form>
```

However, unless you run this on the Arduino itself you'll need to enable [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: Elliott Frisch That works fantastically! I can turn my lights on and off and unlock my door just from running that code snippet! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MichaelHarker Glad to hear it's working. I noticed your comment above included *`input type=submit name=all value=on`*, so I slightly modified it for when you want to turn all the lights off (and maybe not unlock the door)?

Comment: That works great. How do I get that into a HTML page?

Comment: @MichaelHarker Which part? Everything from `<form>` to `</form>` goes somewhere in your `<body>`; you can add the javascript to a `<script>` tag (usually in the `<head>`).

Comment: What code is that written in? I only know basic HTML and CSS.

Comment: [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks Elliott that's just awesome!

Comment: Quick question. How can i style those buttons? Is there a place we can chat? I don't have  enough rep for the chat here.

Comment: @MichaelHarker However you like, embed them in `<ul>` tags (group those in `<div>`s) add css and go nuts man. You could also add `id`(s) and do the same. Really whatever you want.

Comment: could you give me a quick sample of how i would do that of a google link?